# What does the phrase "get you settled" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "get you settled" mean in the following text from the description of a base-building game:

> You are welcome, our new base manager. We’d love to **get you settled**
> but there are thirsty hordes demolishing the walls.

Also, I am interested in knowing about the function of the word "get" in the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

"get" can mean "[to become](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition%20of%20get&oq=definition%20of%20get)" or "cause to become", as in "get the form signed" in the example below.

3. enter or reach a specified state or condition; become.
   "it's getting late"

- used with past participle to form the passive mood.
  "the cat got groomed"
- cause to be treated in a specified way.
  "get the form signed by a doctor"
- induce or prevail upon (someone) to do something.
  "Sophie got Beth to make a fire"
- have the opportunity to do.
  "he got to try out a few of these new cars"
- begin to be or do something, especially gradually or by chance.
  "we got talking one evening"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Raadin.

I am wondering if the word "get" conveys that the manager is being helped by the speaker in the process of settling. Or, is the process of settling done by the manager and the word "get" has no "agent" connotation here?

Comment: If there were enough time, the speaker would get the manager settled.  That is, the speaker would perform the action (along with other people since he said "we"). The sentence is saying that the speaker would do that.